# If then and column.Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to implement this small logic just let me know if I am doing it right?

```
If ( Table1.ColA = 2 and Table2.colB = 4)

    Then Table1.ColC = 5
```

How do I implement some thing like this is SQL?

Comment: Sql-server and MySql are two very different databases. You tagged for both. Which one are you really using?

Comment: And where do you want to implement it? When you insert rows?

Comment: Are you updating a third table `Table` or is `ColC` on `Table1` or `Table2` and just not specified?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: If you want to Update a column on SQL SERVER, can you use **CASE** statement

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek  Let's say, I have 2 columns ColA and ColB in Table 1 and I was the value or ColC based on the above mentioned logic then I need to perform this.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two tables?  How are you relating them?  Is there some common ID field?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, assuming it's all in a single table, it's

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET ColC = 5
   WHERE ColA = 2 AND ColB = 4
```

This will only update rows where that condition is true - it won't touch any others.

Comment: According to the original question they are not all in the same table.  `ColA` is in `Table1`.  `ColB` is in `Table2`.  `ColC` is in `Table`.

Comment: Right, but they amended that in a comment posted to the question, making it sound (I hesitate to use the word "clarifying") like all three columns are in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server (and Oracle, but probably not MySQL)

```
UPDATE Table SET ColC=
(
    DECODE(Table1.ColA
        2,  DECODE(Table2.ColB
            4,  5
            Table.ColC
        )
        Table.ColC
    )
)
```

Comment: Hmm… I'm not seeing a DECODE function in the SQL documentation. Can you show me where it is?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some type of relationship between `Table1` and `Table2`, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET ColC = 5
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Table1ID = t1.ID
WHERE
    t1.ColA = 2
    AND t2.ColB = 4
```